# i can't figure out the bug in my program for calculating permutations

Tags: c, permutation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
int i,j,k,x,y,n=4,a[]={1,2,3,4};   //n is the length of the array
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  for(k=0;k<(n-2);k++)
   {
    for(j=(n-1-k);j>=1;j--)
     {
      y=a[j];
      a[j]=a[j-1];
      a[j-1]=y;
      for(x=0;x<n;x++)
        {
         printf("%d",a[x]);
        }
      printf("\t");
     }
   }
}
getch();
}
```

Comment: I think something went wrong when you submitted your question. The formatting is messed up and there is code missing. Can you fix your question?

Comment: Care to explain what the bug is?

Comment: For this program i am getting only 20 permutations not 24   ..

Answer (score 2):

Some additional material (I'm a bit drunk, I will probably have to re-edit this tomorrow, so take it with a grain of salt):

Knuth and Sedgewick both covered permutations aeons ago.

Have a look at: http://www.princeton.edu/~rblee/ELE572Papers/p137-sedgewick.pdf

For n items you have n! permutations, so for 13 items you already have 6 227 020 800 permutations. So creating all permutations for a large set of items will become impossible pretty fast.

There are basically two sets of algorithms to create permutations, ranking/unranking and incremental change methods.

With ranking/unranking you have two methods rank and unrank.

Rank will give you the position of a permutation in the genereration order.

Unrank will give you the permutation that lies at integer m, with 0 >= m <= **n!** and n the amount of items you want to create permutations for.

This is useful for a variety of cases such as:

Creating a random permutation (you just create a random number from 0 to n! and call unrank(randomNumber)) and get the permutation at position randomNumber.

Creating sequences, getting the next permutation: You have a permutation p and call Rank(p) then Unrank(rank+1).

Incremental change methods:

These basically work through swapping and are more efficient than ranking/unranking:

From wikipedia, unordered generation:

```
 function permutation(k, s) {
     for j = 2 to length(s) {
        swap s[(k mod j) + 1] with s[j]; // note that our array is indexed starting at 1
        k := k / j;        // integer division cuts off the remainder
     }
     return s;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
for(k=0;k<(n-2);k++)
```

to this:

```
for(k=0;k<(n-1);k++)
```

Also, try using more descriptive variable names...

Comment: that doesn't fix the algorithm. 24 results don't mean 24 correct results.

Comment: Precisely. The algorithm is wrong, simply because it obviously doesn't output `n!` times.

Comment: I know the asker's algorithm isn't correct, but he wasn't asking about correctness; he was asking us to find the "bug" that generated 20 instead of 24 permutations, which I did. For all I know he has a very good reason for wanting to use that particular algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the point of your program, but you may try to read the implementation of std::next_permutation. Generating all permutations with loops is somewhat tricky and I prefer using recursion.

Comment: +1, although I don't think that a beginner in C will be happy to parse templated C++ code that uses iterators. There is, however, a nice article about `next_permutation`: http://marknelson.us/2002/03/01/next-permutation/